# Single MOSFET can't handle Lego Medium Motor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, motor, dc-motor

I took some Lego medium motors and replaced their damaged cords with wires for VCC and GND.
I am trying to drive the motors as part of a simple light-following robot, but can only do so by paralleling two IRF830 MOSFETs.

The motor starts working after a longer amount of time when only using one MOSFET and the transistor is much hotter than before.

The power supply is for simplicity's sake also of lego origin and outputs about 9-9.5V.

The circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjl1co.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**How can I get rid of the second MOSFET?**

For reference:

- [Current draws of different LEGO motors](https://philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm)
- [Bricks stack exchange answer on motor current draw](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2127)

**EDIT after component purchase and further experimentation**

- I did buy the low-RDS(on), low-VGS(th) MOSFET IRLZ44NPBF and tested it with my Lego motors and they functioned well enough with no excess heat to speak of.
- The IRF830s I had were unfortunately fakes.
- I also encountered problems with the LDRs, some had too low of a resistance at room illuminance, but this was resolved by buying new ones, bigger value potentiometers and using a small-signal BJT to invert the signal at the gate of the MOSFET.
- I stopped working on the light-following robot as one of the only two medium motors I had released its magic smoke, but the process has certainly been educational.

My sincere thanks to the kind users who helped me better understand the matter at hand!

Comment: The problem here is almost certainly that you're not providing a high enough gate voltage to turn the MOSFET fully on. If you want the motor speed to vary with the amount of light, a better idea would be to use the LDR to control a PWM output.

Comment: This fet has an on resistance of 1.5 ohms - it is not an appropriate fet for low voltages and higher currents.

Comment: @Bryan Well it was the only one I had on hand. How low should RDS(on) be in order to qualify for such applications?

Comment: It's a design that doesn't consider the gate drive level requirements of the MOSFETs and, by the comment from Bryan, it's a poor choice given its relatively high on-resistance.

Comment: I don't quite understand the bit about the "gate drive level requirements". I measured VGS to be about 7V when first shinning the light on the LDR.

Comment: You should use an IRFZ44 or similar (?).

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs without knowing the current requirements of the motor under this specific load I can’t say for sure, but my gut feel is 100mohm or less. With regards to gate drive as others have mentioned: 7V is sufficient for this FET,  however at lower light levels this may not be the case.

Comment: @Bryan I understand. I will buy some low RDS(on) MOSFETs and test the new circuit. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Bryan "7V is sufficient for this FET" - The figure of 1.5 Ohms you quoted is at a Vgs of 10 V, so at 7 it'll be even higher.

Comment: "7V is sufficient for this FET" The gate threshold voltage is not what you care about when using a MOSFET as a digital switch. THat's the voltage it just barely starts to conduct at, but you want maximum conduction.

Comment: According to the datasheet https://www.vishay.com/docs/91063/91063.pdf this FET will conduct about 5A at a Vds of 9V with a Vgs of 7V, so we're well above the threshold. Y'all are correct that we wont have 1.5 ohms drain to source - i get a maximum of 3.33 ohms at 7V using the curve on Id vs Vgs, that sound reasonable?

Comment: ... however my reading of Ids vs Vds just above that suggest that for Vds<10V there's no difference between a Vgs of 7V and 10V (or even 15V). @Finbarr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want ON/OFF control of the motor based on the LDR? You might use a 555 to sense the light and drive the gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEJISX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Motor Current]

This shows about 500 mV on M1 for motor current of 300 mA, or 150 mW. V(ds)on is about 1.6 ohms. For a 1 A motor, it would dissipate about 1.6 watts and 1.6 V drop. An IRF530 would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I didn't have at the time the 555s needed for your circuit schematic, so I replaced it with a BJT set up as a signal inverter. So I did use the overall idea of driving the FET with another semiconductor device.

Answer (score 0):

With this circuit, you can evaluate id, Vd, and power across MOSFET.
Note that IRF830 MOSFET is a "high" voltage device ... Not recommended for this use.

Variable along x-axe is the value of R3 (LDR), and the parameter is the R2 value.

One can see that the MOSFET power is not too high, the "feedback" voltage of the motor should lower it.
The max power dissipation of IRFZ44 MOSFET is 95 W, here it is a maximum of 18 W.

[image]